# If column A contains x AND column B contains y THEN add value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to macros (it's been a few days now!) but slowly working my way through. I'd like to create a macro that *adds* a value of 2 to a cell if column D contains the text "(2)" AND column AG contains the text "Adult".

I've created a macro that so far changes the value of the cell to 5 (instead of adding to it) if column D contains the text "(2)" - I've spent a while messing around with "And" functions but I can't seem to find a way to make it take into account the both the "(2)" text in the D column *and* the "Adult" text in the AG column (I can only make it search one or the other).

Here's my attempt (this doesn't include any of my failed attempts to include the "Adult" text):

```
Sub BUBFindGuests()
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SrchRng = Range("D1:D" & lastRow, "AG1:AG" & lastRow)
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "(2)") > 0 Then
            With cel.Offset(0, 39)
                .Offset(-1, 0) = "5"
            End With
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

I'm basically just trying to work out how to include the "Adult" text from the AG column, and also how to make the macro *add* rather than *change* the end value. I'm also relatively certain that some parts of my code are unnecessary or clunky, but with my level of experience I'm unsure of how to correct that. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "Change the end value"...not sure what you mean, are you trying to add 2 to the value of a cell in a specific column?  Are you trying to add 2 to the end of a string (word)?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. I am trying to add 2 to the value of a cell in a specific column.

Also would like to thank everyone who has posted - although I can only accept one answer, all responses have really helped me to further my understanding of VBA. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your code, you want to *add* 2 to column C, if that's the case this should do the trick:

```
Sub BUBFindGuests()

lastRow = Sheets("SHEETNAME").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 to lastRow
  If InStr(1, Sheets("SHEETNAME").Cells(x, 4), "(2)") <> 0 _ 'Checks column D
  And Instr(1, Sheets("SHEETNAME").Cells(x, 33), "Adult") <> 0 Then 'Checks column AG
    Sheets("SHEETNAME").Cells(x, 3).Value = _
    Sheets("SHEETNAME").Cells(x, 3).Value + 2 'Change 3 to the appropriate column 
  End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: While I was working out the kinks to my code just like this on "sheet4", I got stung and would suggest you change you definition of your last row to `lastrow=Sheets("SHEETNAME").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`  Alternatively you could wrap all that code in a With statement.

Comment: FWIW, I think `Cells(x, "AG")` is a lot easier to debug than `Cells(x, 33)` ;-)

Comment: That's true, thanks. I only ever use R1C1 formats so was just force of habit

Answer (score 2):

You can search for **Adult** just as you searched for the **(2)**. Just use the InStr-function two times and combine the result-booleans. You can do that in two ways, logical with **And** or nested with two if-statements:

- `If InStrResult1 **And** InStrResult2 Then 'do stuff End If`
- `If InStrResult1 Then If InStrResult2 Then 'do stuff End If End If`

Sorry for the bad formation.

You can then store the current value of your cell in a variable. Then add 2 to that variable (`myVariable = myVariable + 2`) and then set its value to your cell instead of 5.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: It turns out I misread your question. See revised code.

```
Sub BUBFindGuests()

    Dim SrchRng As Range
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SrchRng = Range("D1:D" & lastRow, "AG1:AG" & lastRow)
    For Each cel In SrchRng

        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "(2)") > 0 And InStr(1, cel.Value, "Adult") > 0 Then cel.Offset(-1, 39).Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value & "5"

    Next cel

End Sub
```